# Executing a test in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am pretty new with TCL but I am writing a script that will search a file for testcases and filter out ones with specific key words and run these test using `exec`. It runs the first test fine but once it completes it begins to run the same test again and instantly fails cause my script to end. This is what the script looks like that runs a test

```
exec make clean
exec make depends
set runtests [exec bsub -I -q lin_i make test_run_test_here SEED=1 VPDDUMP=on]
set test [lsearch -all -inline $runtest "TEST COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY: test_run_test_here"]
puts $test
```

it runs throught the test fine but after I get this message

```
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
<<Starting on testserver01>>
    while executing
"exec bsub -I -q lin_i make test_run_test_here SEED=1 VPDDUMP=on"
    invoked from within
"set runtests [exec bsub -I -q lin_i make test_run_test_here SEED=1 VPDDUMP=on]"
    (file "./test.tcl" line 71)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exec` command considers it a failure if the called command outputs anything to stderr, even if it has a successful exit status:

> If any of the commands writes to its standard error file and that standard error is not redirected and -ignorestderr is not specified, then exec will return an error;

- http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm

You want to use the `-ignorestderr` option.

```
set runtests [exec -ignorestderr bsub ...
```

Comment: Thank you this did exactly what I needed it to do! It seems so simple I don't know how I missed it...

Comment: The only truly awful problems occur when the program both insists on writing non-error stuff to stderr while not consistently returning a non-zero exit code on error. That's when you have to do something nasty like reading everything into a string and parsing it with regexps. Horrible. Worth reporting as a bug to the creator of the program that works that way (if you think they'll listen…)